# how to get category-name by category-id from wordpress rest-api

Tags: wordpress

After using WordPress rest-api, i'm able to get all post.
but on the JSON it only have the category ID. How Can i generate the category name from this.
this is the api:

```
https://blog.lifeforcecare.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please use [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) function. I have attached below example code.

```
$category_detail=get_the_category('4');//$post->ID
foreach($category_detail as $cd){
   echo $cd->cat_name;
}
```